# How to use the Rails shopify_app gem with a private API key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, shopify

I am trying to use the Rails *shopify_app* gem with a private API key. The documentation for the gem mentions that it's possible to do this but doesn't say how. The instructions are only for a Shopify Partner Account.

For a private api key there seems to be no way of specifying the *return url*. This results in the following response fragment being sent back:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The redirect_uri and application url must have matching hosts"}
```

I've looked around a bit but was not able to find a solution to this. It seems like this should be better documented on Shopify API wiki. I'd appreciate any help with this.

cheers,

-tomek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to request permission? You should be able to use the password generated for the private key as the access token since permission has already been granted.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. I don't understand how to use the password generated for the private key. Where am I supposed to plug it in? The app generator asks for the private key and secret and puts those values in application.rb. Where would I put the password string?

Comment: One more thing, please not that I'm trying to use shopify_app and not shopify_api. The names are very similar so it's easy to miss. I can successfully use shopify_api gem, no problems there. It's the Rails app generator that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: The app gem doesn't really get you anything since its a private app and permission is already granted. Is there something in particular from the app gem you want to use? Either way you still need to initialize the Shopify API gem with the correct credentials, the app gem doesn't do this for you.

Comment: I did not know about the need initialise Shopify API separately. I assumed that the App gem would do this for me but was stumped when I couldn't find any way to grant permission to my app. Thanks for clarifying this for me John.

Comment: It will initialize the session the first time when granting permission (if using oauth) but later on you don't want to always have to grant permission yourself so you will want to initialize it yourself based on the user that is using the app. Your case is pretty different since a private app already has permission granted so you don't need that step. Really, the main point to the app gem is to handle the permissions dance which you don't need.

Comment: And further to this, I moved away from using the Rails generator and just wrote a simple Sinatra app on top of Shopify API to do my testing. It was very simple and effective. Thanks for all the help.