# Shopify shopify_app generator private app in combination with shopify_api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, shopify

A continuation of this question really:
[How to use the Rails shopify_app gem with a private API key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274135/how-to-use-the-rails-shopify-app-gem-with-a-private-api-key)

I have a Shopify App generated with the shopify_app gem, all working fine.

I want to 'convert' this to a private app with the primary aim of having offline access to run scheduled tasks.

Using the shopify_api gem via irb is all working fine and I can update orders etc that way, but initialising the shopify_api session for the private app is what I'm struggling with now.

1. Is it best to re-install the app to gain the access token I need or can I access this some other way?
2. Is it best to write another controller to handle the private app or can I make use of those provided with the shopify_app gem?

I've read the instructions below (and lots of other shopify documentation), so it's not a case of not looking, I just need a little extra guidance:
http://wiki.shopify.com/Using_the_shopify_api_gem_with_the_credentials_of_a_private_application

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is initialize the ShopifyAPI::Session with the password you were given. You're probably doing this in a before filter somewhere? Instead of initializing with the access_token use the password you have.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your response. At the moment I've not altered the default shopify_app generated application. I can see that this uses the "around_filter :shopify_session" to pass in the credentials from the current session i.e. the store that was entered upon installing/logging in. Do I need to create a separate controller to handle the offline access or are you saying I can just replace the access_token for the password in the current (default) controller? When you say 'password' is this the password that is referenced on /admin/api?

Comment: For offline access you would not have a controller available, you would need to initialize the ShopifyAPI::Session directly. You're also mentioning installing/logging in which isn't relevant for you case since it's a private app. An API permission is already generated, the API permission linking an API key and Shop is what makes an app 'installed'

Comment: Thanks John, I understand now. I've followed the steps here:http://wiki.shopify.com/Using_the_shopify_api_gem_with_the_credentials_of_a_private_application And in a rake task I'm initialising the shopify session directly using: ShopifyAPI::Base.site = "https://username:password@some-shop.myshopify.com/admin"